# BCS - Cannot open server requested by the login. The Login Failed

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, sql

I am trying to create an external list from my Azure DB using BCS. I already setup the SQL, and I was able to connect to it through SSMS. But when I tried SPD to create external content type I am getting the following.

Note: the username and password I added in my secure store is the same account I used to login using SSMS.

Note: I also set the firewall in my SQL server to allow any IP address because I thought its being blocked but still getting the same error.

Note: I also tried creating a new sql login and add it on the secure store but still same error. I also tried different format for username like:

username@servername

servername\username

username

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell how did you resolve this error ? what do you mean by "I need to add a BCS item in the BCS column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where I made mistake, I need to add a BCS item in the BCS column. Also @server is not required to the Secure Store for SQL auths